# Python application using eel "unable to connect" to localhost on startup

Tags: python, ubuntu, firefox, eel

I am trying to create a python application while using eel to create a user interface in html.  My operating system is Ubuntu Linux and I'm using Firefox to display the web interface.

The problem I'm having is every time I run the python code, Firefox opens a blank page saying "Unable to connect" followed by "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8000".  However, if I click the "Try Again" button once, twice, or three times, my interface is displayed.

Once open, I can navigate to different pages but I also noticed that once I navigate to a different page, some of my javascript stops working (specifically a window.close() function).  I don't know if this is related but I thought I would mention it just in case.

Any advice on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my browser from firefox to chromium and now my interface loads on startup the first time.  I know some documentation says it can be used with firefox, and it can, but it seems to be kind of buggy and works better with other browsers.

However, I'm still having trouble with my javascript not running but that will be another question.